# Animate image through Angular 2

Tags: css, angular, typescript, ionic2

I was wondering how I could apply an animation on a specific image in my project. The project consists of a group of questions that are shown with a kind of progress bar. The zombie is set depending on how many questions were answered. Each answered question moves the zombie one step further.

As you can see, I use `style.left` to set where the zombie should be.

HTML:

```
<div class="animation-content">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="assets/moonwalk.gif" class="walk" [style.left]="positionAvatar">
  </div>
  <span class="track"></span>
  <span class="flag"></span>
</div>
```

TS:

```
 if(this.setProgressBar.progress(this.answeredQuestions.length, this.theme.data.length) > 0) {
   this.positionAvatar = (this.setProgressBar.progress(this.answeredQuestions.length, this.theme.data.length) * 0.9) + "%";
 }
```

Result:

[image: Wololo]

However, I didn't figure out how I could add a transition effect to it. I tried through CSS, but it didn't work out. I would like to have a smooth transition after changing its position. How could I make it using either CSS or Angular 2? Thanks :)

Comment: so `.walk {transition: left .5s;}` in CSS doesn't work?

Comment: @Und3rTow I was using the `animate` property, so it wasn't working. But I used `transition` as you said and it worked! Thank you!